# Creating OFFSETA field for viewshed analysis in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, 3d-analyst, viewshed, visibility

I'm trying to create a viewshed where the observer point is a person standing. I have the point feature but it didn't come with an OFFSETA field, which I know is how you set the observer height.

How do I add and populate this field with the correct height?

I'm using ArcMap 10.4.

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to specify that the value being added to OFFSETA is in vertical meters. does the system just assume that any value entered under that field name is in vertical units?

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/using-viewshed-and-observer-points-for-visibility.htm says "The OFFSETA item indicates a vertical distance in surface units to be added to the z-value of the observation point."  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise it with any requested clarifications,

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: When I create an OFFSETA field, what type of field should it be? (i.e. float, string, short integer etc.) I just tried it as a short integer and it was automatically rounding everything up instead of letting me have decimals.

Comment: There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise it with any requested clarifications,

Answer (score 2):

The OFFSETA Field's value is based on the coordinate system used in dataframe / layer in which the field is found.

If your layer in in UTM, then the value in OFFSETA will be metres, conversely if your layer is projected in feet, then the OFFSETA vertical distance will be in feet.

To create an OFFSETA field, simply open the attribute table of your "person" point layer, click the drop down in the "Table Options" and select "Add Field".

Call the field "OFFSETA" and make it "Double".
Once you have added it, right-click the field and choose the field calculator and assign a height in metres / feet above ground level.

Run your viewshed.
You can have many different points and many different OFFSETA Values.

Hope that clarifies the OFFSETA question you had.